# Cómo hacer pivot dinámico con inner join en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta consulta, pero yo quiero que se visualice en un solo registro y la cantidadSurtido en otra columna, como máximo tendré 3 cantidadSurtido por registro. Se que esto puede ser posible con PIVOT dinámico pero no lo he logrado.
La primer imagen es el resultado de la consulta que tengo actualmente, la segunda es el resultado que espero obtener con ayuda de PIVOT.

Mi consulta es:

```
    SELECT VD.Cantidad, 
           VD.Unidad, 
           VD.Descripcion, 
           VD.Destino, 
           S.Cantidad as CantidadSurtido 
      FROM VALE_DETALLE VD
INNER JOIN VALE V
        ON VD.IdVale = V.IdVale
INNER JOIN SURTIDO S
        ON VD.IdValeDetalle = S.IdValeDetalle
     WHERE VD.IdVale = 2
```

[image: Consulta actual]

[image: Este es el resultado que yo espero]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
El código va como texto, así como no te van a responder con imagenes para ponerte a transcribir. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. ¿Usas SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si siempre vas a tener un máximo de 3 surtidos, lo mejor es que no uses un pivot dinámico sino que se quede de forma estático en 3. Eso se puede hacer de forma sencilla dando un identificador a cada linea de surtido con la función `ROW_NUMBER()`. Después es solo cuestión de un agregado condicional que es preferible al operador `PIVOT`.

```
WITH cteSurtidoVales AS(
    SELECT VD.Cantidad, 
           VD.Unidad, 
           VD.Descripcion, 
           VD.Destino, 
           S.Cantidad as CantidadSurtido,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY VD.IdVale, VD.IdValeDetalle ORDER BY S.Cantidad) rn --En vez de S.Cantidad, es preferible poner alguna columna que de un orden veraz
    FROM VALE_DETALLE  VD
    INNER JOIN VALE    V  ON VD.IdVale = V.IdVale
    INNER JOIN SURTIDO S  ON VD.IdValeDetalle = S.IdValeDetalle
    WHERE VD.IdVale = 2
)
SELECT  Cantidad, 
        Unidad, 
        Descripcion, 
        Destino, 
        SUM( CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN CantidadSurtido /*ELSE 0*/ END) AS CantidadSurtido1, 
        SUM( CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN CantidadSurtido /*ELSE 0*/ END) AS CantidadSurtido2, 
        SUM( CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN CantidadSurtido /*ELSE 0*/ END) AS CantidadSurtido3
FROM cteSurtidoVales
GROUP BY Cantidad, 
         Unidad, 
         Descripcion, 
         Destino;
```

Comment: La he editado, ya que en lugar de Cantidad después del THEN era CantidadSurtido